# Android UnsatisfiedLinkError: Issue loading a shared library

Tags: android, java-native-interface, shared-libraries

I am compiling some Java code, putting it into a .JAR and then running dx --dex on it. I am pushing my file to an Android device through adb but I am having problem linking my shared library at runtime.

In HostConnection.java, I have the following code to load my library:

```
static {
    System.loadLibrary("hostConnection");
}
```

I am loading the application this way:

```
adb shell
su
export CLASSPATH=/data/local/device.jar
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/data/local/libhostConnection.so
exec app_process /system/bin com.device.client.Main
```

I am unfortunately getting the following error:

```
D/dalvikvm( 1616): DexOpt: load 482ms, verify 84ms, opt 10ms
D/dalvikvm( 1608): DexOpt: --- END 'device.jar' (success) ---
D/dalvikvm( 1608): DEX prep '/data/local/device.jar': unzip in 1715ms, rewrite 1287ms
W/dalvikvm( 1608): Exception Ljava/lang/UnsatisfiedLinkError; thrown during Lcom/device/client/HostConnection;.<clinit>
D/AndroidRuntime( 1608): Shutting down VM
W/dalvikvm( 1608): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d830)
I/Process ( 1608): Sending signal. PID: 1608 SIG: 9
E/AndroidRuntime( 1608): *** FATAL EXCEPTION IN SYSTEM PROCESS: main
E/AndroidRuntime( 1608): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
E/AndroidRuntime( 1608):    at com.device.client.Main.<init>(Main.java:27)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1608):    at com.device.client.Main.main(Main.java:21)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1608):    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.finishInit(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1608):    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.main(RuntimeInit.java:235)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1608):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1608): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Library hostConnection not found
E/AndroidRuntime( 1608):    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:461)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1608):    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:557)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1620):    at com.device.client.HostConnection.<clinit>(HostConnection.java:25)
```

The line 25 in HostConnection.java is indeed System.loadLibrary("hostConnection").

My library is called libhostConnection.so and my .jar is called device.jar. They are both stored in /data/local. I have tried moving the shared library to /system/lib but the shell does not let me copy the file (read-only).

I am not sure what I am doing wrong, but I believe it cannot find the shared library for linking when running the application. I am not sure if I am using the wrong variable in export, or if I am supposed to do something else.

Could anyone please help me? It would be much appreciated.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. The variable is correct, but the path should be just the folder, not the .so file for some reason:

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/data/local

This actually works.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

And why don't you just try putting your library into lib/armeabi(-v7a) directory in your eclipse project? I believe it's the recomended way of linking shared library.